# Gnome 3.22 dual monitor with workspaces only on primary. Changing workspaces moves the workspace over second monitor.

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, workspaces

I have a dual monitor setup where the secondary monitor (no workspaces) is placed above the primary monitor (with workspaces).

When I change workspaces on my primary monitor, the animation moves the whole workspace e.g. my firefox window, over my secondary monitor. The final result is as it should be, but I don't want to see the window moving over my second (static) monitor. Is there a way to fix this?

The stupid solution is to put the screens next to each otherm as workspace switching is only up/down, but with a laptop+fixed monitor setup this is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this behavior by editing the option in gconf. See this [blog](http://gregcor.com/2011/05/07/fix-dual-monitors-in-gnome-3-aka-my-workspaces-are-broken/) for details.

Comment: That blog post that you refer to is 9 years old.  Is there any more recent guidance?

Comment: Can you confirm if that approach works in Ubuntu Desktop 18.04? - I have the same situation in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245037/ubuntu-does-not-isolate-the-apps-in-the-secondary-monitor-through-each-workspace