# Ubuntu does not isolate the apps in the secondary monitor through each workspace

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, workspaces

I work with Ubuntu Desktop 18.04

Furthermore I have Windows 10 and MacOS working with multi desktops. I know how create a new one and how move through them

An important observation is that for each laptop is that each one has a secondary monitor. I am able to open any application (editor, window explorer or finder, terminal console, an IDE - etc) and move it to the secondary monitor. Therefore some applications are in the primary monitor and others in the secondary monitor.

The point here is, for each Desktop, I am able to have in the primary and secondary monitors any application. If I pass through these Desktops each Desktop respects and keeps isolated the same set of applications opened and distributed through the primary and secondary monitors from the beginning. Again it for each Desktop.

After to did do a research to accomplish the same goal in Ubuntu, I did realize that *multi desktop* is referred how *workspace*. Well, I am able to move through them with `Ctrl + Alt [up|down]`.

**Problem**: all the content (app) opened in the secondary monitor is shared through all the workspace, therefore the apps are not isolated through each workspace.

In `Settings -> Devices -> Displays` there is no a special settings to have the same behavior like the two other OS

How to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make gnome-shell treat both monitors in the same way?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68778/how-can-i-make-gnome-shell-treat-both-monitors-in-the-same-way)

Comment: The instructions shown below work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**:

Install `gnome-tweaks` (it was named *gnome-tweak-tool* before)

- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt upgrade`
- `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

To execute *gnome-tweaks* open a terminal and execute `gnome-tweaks`

It opens a dialog, it has a vertical menu located in the left, in the the bottom select the `Workspaces` and do click in the `Workspaces span displays` option. Therefore that option must have now a black arrow now (how a check).

Comment: works like charm. Thanks man